# How to assemble to Arduino UNO R3 (atmega 16u2)?

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr

I'm learning about assembly programming for Arduino over GNU/Linux, using as test board an Arduino UNO R3 with AVR Atmega 16u2 microcontroller.

As I read in this article https://www.cypherpunk.at/2014/09/native-assembler-programming-on-arduino/ the instructions must be:

`avr-as -g -mmcu=atmega16u2 -o simple_led_blink.o simple_led_blink.s` #to assemble

`avr-ld -o simple_led_blink.elf simple_led_blink.o` #to link

But, when I try to execute this second instruction, it shows this error:

`` avr-ld: avr:35 architecture of input file `simple_led_blink.o' is incompatible with avr output ``

I've checked in avr-as architecture support, and this architecture is supported.

What could be the problem?

Update: Finally, as David says, the main microcontroller is the 328p,not 16u2 
I use the instructions as been written in the guide, and it runs well

Comment: It doesn't work with mcu `atmega16u2`. Try with `atmega328`

Comment: @Sniper With atmega328 runs, but my board has a atmega16u2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running `avr-gcc test.c -v -mmcu=atmega16u2` we can tell that the correct AVR architecture version for ATmega16U2 is `avr35`.

So to compile your assembly, run commands like this:

```
avr-as -mavr35 -g -o test.o test.s
avr-ld -mavr35 -o test.elf test.o
```

Note that you might need to pass additional options to the linker to ensure that the program size and RAM size are set correctly, but that will probably not matter if your program is small.

Also note that the ATmega16U2 is not the main processor on the Arduino UNO; the main one is an ATmega328P.

I don't know why the `-mmcu` option in the tutorial would not work any more.  Perhaps the AVR port of binutils was simplified in recent years to only know about AVR architectures and not know about every single chip.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: Ok, I'm reading about this in Arduino site, and the 16u2 feels be the microcontroller to usb-serial converter.

Previously I changed the firmware with dfu, and this possibly confused me.